# Connect to MS Access with unixodbc

Tags: linux, fedora, unixodbc

I wonder if there is a way do connect to MS Access database mdb accdb?
Now after installing EasySoft unixodbc (with trial lic) i have this response when i try connect to base:

```
<pre>
SQL Status: HY000
[unixODBC][Easysoft ODBC]General error: OS Version mismatch: Please report this sequence (AAAF, LX, 3, -1, -1) to Easysoft support at support@easysoft.com
</pre>
```

An additional note: this moment i have two version of inuxodbc on system one installed by yum and other installed by Easysoft installer the last
odbc.ini i show below:

```
<pre>
[ACCESS_SAMPLE]
Description=Easysoft ODBC-Access Driver
Driver=Easysoft ODBC-ACCESS
mdbfile=/home/1c/Access/wer.mdb
smbpath=
lockfile=
smblib=
smbuser=
smbauth=
readonly=yes
exclusive=no
ignore_rel=no
</pre>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel 3 is not currently supported by the [Easysoft ODBC-Access driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html). Contact Easysoft support and let them know the error and if you are using a 64-bit or 32-bit application and they will be able to give you access to the pre-release version which support Kernel 3.

Comment: it is supported as well it run on my fedora. the only disadvantage no russian characters  support in database as well european languages too only 7-bit coded table.

Comment: @Yurij73 Now supports UTF8 configurable by the attribute unicode_map=2

Comment: @RichardSpencer Hi can you look into my question as well regarding Easysoft JDBC Access Driver [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74916967/how-do-i-give-a-database-path-to-odbc-microsoft-access-driver-with-ampersand-in). Thanks!