# How do I give a database path to ODBC Microsoft Access Driver with ampersand in it?

Tags: ms-access, jdbc-odbc

My database path name has an ampersand in it. "...\mthly calcs & projections...".

Unfortunately, the path name cannot be changed. How do I deal with this case? Is there a way to specify the database path to the driver so it accepts the path with an ampersand? Maybe escaping it somehow or encoding it differently?

In the connection string if I use "&" doesn't work because ";" is interpreted as an option delimiter.

```
"jdbc:easysoft:mdb?DBQ=...\\mthly calcs & projections\\...\\Databases\\myDatabase.accdb;ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;READONLY=False;EXCLUSIVE=True"
```

I tested it by changing the path name by replacing the "&" with "and" and it works fine. Unfortunately in the production version the path names are fixed and I can't change them to remove the "&".

Comment: Asked this question in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244425/general-error-unable-to-open-registry-key-temporary-volatile-from-access) of an older question but no response.

Comment: Try `mthly calcs %26 projections` or possibly `mthly+calcs+%26+projections`

Comment: if you are connecting from Access try using the character code for &.  "\\mthly calcs " & char(38) & "projections\\"  if you are connecting from elsewhere try finding the equivalent for the vba function char()

Comment: @GordThompson Tried `%26` for `&`.
@mazoula Tried `FromCharacterCode[38]` also doesn't work. `38` is just the character code for `&` so it produces the same connection string.

Answer (score 0):

*Escaping* the ampersand should work:

```
"jdbc:easysoft:mdb?DBQ=...\\mthly calcs \& projections\\...\\Databases\\myDatabase.accdb;ExtendedAnsiSQL=1;READONLY=False;EXCLUSIVE=True"
```

Comment: Escaping the `&` by `\&` also doesn't work.

Comment: Oh. How about doubling it: `&&`.